# Backbone pushstate not catching routes, settting "root" properly

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate, backbone-routing

I think I'm missing something basic but I can't find out what, I've checked other post on this topîc but couldn't find a clear answer.

The url launching my app is:

```
http://local.myapp.ngx:8080/myapp/fileasset/app.html
```

app.html is loading require/main.js

// MAIN.JS

initializing the router:

```
      new Router();
```

starting history:

```
Backbone.history.start({
            pushState: true,
            root: "/myapp/fileasset/"
});
```

// ROUTER.JS

```
    routes: {
        '':'test'
    }
```

==> PROBLEM , test function is never called.

if I try this:

```
routes: {
    '*wtv':'test'
}
```

==> THEN "test" is triggered but how to catch other routes ?

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was a really really basic thing, I didn't put the right root

```
            root: "/myapp/fileasset/ui.html"
```